# zf.php: command not found ubuntu 12 Zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework2, ubuntu-12.04, config

I have downloaded and extracted the ZendSkeletonApplication as said in the 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Now when the try installing the zftool by follwing the document

1.http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html
when typed 
composer require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
i got Error: 
No command 'composer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'compose' from package 'mime-support' (main)
composer: command not found

So tried Manual installation

Extracted and placed as said in manual
i have installed the ZFTool here: 
/var/www/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/ZFTool
[image]

This also says Error:
zf.php: command not found

Not sure what else is creating problem.

Can you guys, please provide with a step by step way of installing zftool

Comment: Composer is used to download library files of zend framework2. In terminal, go to your project folder and run `php composer.phar install`. automatically it will install the library files in that folder. Before you run check `composer.phar` and `composer.json` file is available in your path

Comment: Dont install it manually as it wont be added to autoloader & wont have a file added to bin directory. Get composer working, use as suggested above > php composer.phar install

Answer (score 0):

Place yourself in the root of the project

On Linux run command find -name zf.php just to find the location of the file under your project.

If you find it - mine was under vendor/bin, run the following command:

```
php vendor/bin/zf.php create module Test
```

This command will create the Test Module.